# How can I get the link to my product page in opencart 3.0

Tags: opencart

I just want to show the product link to my product page externally between div tags.

the code below only gives the link to my website. I am a beginner in this subject please help

```
{% if products %}
<a href="{{ product.href }}"> {{product.name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you should add $data['products'] in controller then use this array in view
please attach controller and view  to help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show your product URL in the page you should first edit your controller to seem like this

```
$data['products'] = array(
    // some another data
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
);
```

and then you can use

```
{% if products %}
<a href="{{ product.href }}"> {{product.name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem, I successfully sent the page that the whatsapp customer last entered by calling the last of the navigation link on the same page.                                  
{% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
         {% if loop.last %}